# How to have multiple bugzilla releases co-existing in parallel on one server (e.g. 2.21 and 3.x) for trialling

Tags: installation, version, bugzilla

I run bugzilla 2.21 on Debian Linux and I would like to take advantage of the enhancements and features in the latest release of bugzilla, at time of writing this is in 3.x numbering, currently 3.44.

I cannot simply upgrade to the new version, because:
- I would like to give my users time to become familiar with the latest version
- Avoids the risk of unavailability of the bugzilla service should there be complications with the upgrade
- My bosses are quiet strict with this sort of thing; I can't be seen to just do an upgrade without some sort of trial, process or consultation. I would think that is reasonable.

What I would like to do is take a snapshot copy of the MySQL database content for the current bugzilla installed release, 2.21. Then use this copy with the latest release installed on the same machine.

The latest release would be entirely separate from the earlier 2.21 release. This means that there would be 2 bugzilla installations running on the same machine, each with its own data.

I would also like the latest version to be read-only. This is so that users continue to use version 2.21 for real work, but the latest version is for trialling, for becoming familiar with the different interface etc.

I would run this trial period for a few weeks, giving users prior notice of the eventual, inevitable upgrade. During the trial I would ask for feedback on the new release.

I have already searched for an answer to this question on the bugzilla mailing list (via Nabble) but no answers, so I posted the question myself a while ago (last March) but no reply.
http://old.nabble.com/Multiple-bugzilla-release-version-installs-co-exist-in-parallel-on-one-server-(e.g.-2.21-and-3.2)-for-trialling-3.2-alongside-td22623349.html

The bugzilla documentation doesn't appear to advise on how to do this either.

What appears to complicate running parallel releases of bugzilla is that the installation (on Debian, at least) puts bugzilla programs and data in at least three places:

/etc/bugzilla
/var/lib/bugzilla
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/bugzilla

If the bugzilla install was all under one folder (e.g. like a Drupal install) then it would be simpler to run multiple versions in parallel.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the Debian package, the normal Bugzilla tarball shipped from bugzilla.org is all in one directory.

You don't have to make your second installation read-only, just set mail_delivery_method to "Test" and put something in announcehtml (these are both Parameters) to indicate that this is just a test installation.

Comment: Thank you very much Max! I will try out your suggestion and update this question with my findings.

Comment: As promised, an update: I have completed the install, with a few minor issues (more on those in a moment). I backed up the original bugzilla SQL database, made a copy of it in a different name and followed the steps in the README that came with the tarball. The most involved (time consuming and with user interaction) step was running the checksetup.pl stage, had to run this several times and install perl modules as it instructed me.

Comment: The minor issue was the failure of PerlMagick to install due to the make failing on a compiler option not available in the latest stable gcc in debian. I have tried to get the latest compiler version so that the compile works but I can't get debian apt-get to get the later version. See my question thread here: http://serverfault.com/questions/94564/how-to-force-debian-linux-apt-get-installer-to-install-unstable-specific-version

Comment: Any thoughts on this minor issue appreciated, but thanks again - I've "upped" your answer.